# Sharing JNI bound library between threads, weird behaviour

Tags: java, c, multithreading, concurrency, java-native-interface

So I have this scenario:

There's a Java Class let's call it OBJ that through JNI calls some methods on C library (LIB) through a C wrapper (WRAP). 
I only have access to OBJ and WRAP source code, i don't see what's in LIB, i just know it exposes some methods that are called by te wrapper (WRAP) which is called through JNI from OBJ.

I'm experiencing very weird behaviour when sharing the OBJ between threads, here's an example:

```
OBJ obj = null;

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        obj = new OBJ();
    }

});

t1.start();
t1.join();

System.out.println("Value from main thread: " + obj.getValue());


Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Value from t2 thread: " + obj.getValue());

    }

});

t2.start();
t2.join();
```

When running the above piece of code the first `System.out.println()` returns incorrect value, whereas the second `System.out.println()` prints the correct one. 
The obj.getValue(), calls a native method (getValueC) on the wrapper, the wrapper calls a method from the library (LIB).
As said, I have no access to LIB, but i'm first trying to make sure there's nothing wrong with my thinking here, is there any difference between the threads t1, t2 and the main thread?
Suprisingly if I instantiate the object in the main thread then both t1 and t2 would print correct values. 
Is it maybe required to instantiate JNI bound objects in the main thread ?

Comment: Is the C library you're calling thread-safe?

Comment: Is `obj` an instance variable or a local variable?  Please provide a [mcve].  Or at least the Java part of one.

Comment: The C library is thread safe when called in C/C++, the wrapper just wraps the library methods so that they can be called from Java